How do I apply src-nat to the traffic coming from ipsec?
I am using StrongSwan to Mikrotik IKEv2 tunnel. I wonder if it is possible to sourcenat what is comming from the ipsec-tunnel on Mikrotik's side?
The problem is that I have a host in my local network that is behind a firewall who's configuration is forbidden. This firewall will only allow connections from the same subnet (lets say 192.168.10.X), but what's coming from the tunnel is sourcenatted to 100.64.10.1, which is rejected by the host mentioned above.
What is also worth mentioning is that on Mikrotik's side I have an IP 100.64.10.2 created by Swan's ipsec configuration.
I've already tried straightforward approach by creating a NAT rule on Mikrotik, but it is being ignored (from my comprehension due to the notrack rules generated by ipsec). I've been also searching through RAW and MANGLE (that are actually working) for a workaround but still netstat on a dummy host will show 100.64.10.1 for incoming IP.
Please help :D
ipsec.conf fragment:
conn arterial
    eap_identity=changed@domain.zone
    left=%any
    leftcert=scert.pem
    lefthostaccess=yes
    leftid=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (public IP)
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=100.64.10.0/28
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    rightsendcert=never
    rightsourceip=100.64.0.2
    rightsubnet=192.168.10.0/16

conn roadwar
    also=arterial
    eap_identity=changed@domain.zone
    rightsourceip=100.64.10.3-100.64.10.15
    rightsubnet=100.64.10.0/28

iptables fragment:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/16 -o enpXsY -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/16 -o enpXsY -j MASQUERADE

Identities on Mikrotik:

Please show us your configuration. What NAT rules have you created? What does your complete firewall configuration look like? What does your network interface configuration look like?

I added some clarification. The firewall on Mikrotik is currently RouterOS default. The firewall on the LAN host is inaccessible.

That rightsubnet=192.168.10.0/16 and rightsourceip=100.64.0.2 combination does not add up. It's either that a virtual IP is assigned to the peer, which will be the source of the traffic, or there is one or more subnets at the other end, not both. So which is it?

This configuration works like a charm for my puproses: to access organization's internal LAN from a roadwarrior. They "meet" in the middle in the 100.64.0.0/28 virtual subnet and then everything is routed to wherever it is destined. Roadwarriors can communicate each other as well. The ONLY question is how to SNAT or MASQUERADE what Mikrotik is getting from it's 100.64.10.2 IP? As it is originally sourcenatted to VIP so it won't pass network-level authentication.

I should've switched notrack chain in ipsec identities on client's side to output instead of prerouting in order to get NAT to work.

Unfortunately, this move slows things down and makes client's router inaccessible from WAN, so I've created raw rule that reverts notrack to prerouting everywhere I don't need that NAT.

Again. The point of this is to access services and devices residing behind firewalls that you cannot configure.
